# How does setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) work?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm a bit of curious when creating the up action button in the action bar.

[image: Action Bar image]

Is that a function like the "back" button ?

Comment: Yes it does. clicking on it would work as hardware back button.

Comment: owhh i see, thankyou :)